# How to make a function where user can input the year and month which automatically find the last day of the month?

Tags: t-sql

I want to write a sql function where user has a text box to input the data where USER can input the year and month to find the last day of the month. 
I have written this query but it is only returning last day of the current month.

```
CreateFunction [dbo].[Date]()
Returns int
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @aint

   set @a=  CAST( Convert(VARCHAR(10), EOMONTH(DateADD(d, -1, GETDATE())),112) As int )
Return @a
End
```

Comment: You've flagged this as MySQL, but this does not look like MySQL syntax?

Comment: So, the last date of the current month (ex: Apr 30, 2019), or the number of the last day of the current month (ex: 30)? Also, "Date" is a reserved word in most languages, you really should name the function "LastDayOfMonth", "EndOfMonth", or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

`EOMONTH` will give you the last day of the month of a specified date.

```
SELECT EOMONTH ( GetDate() ) AS Result;
```

So that will give you 04/30/2019.

You don't really need to create a user defined function for this as `EOMONTH` is already built to do this.

Comment: Worth noting that this works in SQL Server 2012+. The OP hasn't specified a SQL version yet

Comment: Thx Allen. I was going to go into my old method of adding a month then subtracting one millisecond from the first of the following month to get the last day of the month but figured I'd go with EOMOTH

Answer (score 0):

**Function 1** with `year` and `month` as input,

```
create function [dbo].[udf_getEOM_day](@year as int, @month as int)
returns int
AS
BEGIN 
   return day(eomonth(datefromparts(@year,@month,01)))
END
GO
```

**test1** OK.

```
select dbo.udf_getEOM_day(_year,_month) from (values(1991,01)) as t(_year,_month)
```

**Function2** with `date` as input,

```
create function [dbo].[udf_getEOM](@date as date)
returns int
AS
BEGIN 
   return day(eomonth(@date))
END
GO
```

**test2** OK.

```
select dbo.udf_getEOM(_date) from (values(cast( '1991-01-21' as date))) as t(_date)
```

Note you can change the name of the functions. I recommend prepending `udf_` to `user defined functions`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is only returning the last date of the current month that is because you are using `getdate()` function that will give you current date and `EOMONTH` will give you last date of the current month.

To resolve this issue add the `parameter` to the function that will pass user input to the function and you will get the last day of the month.

**Function**

```
Create Function [dbo].[Date](@dt date)
Returns int
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @a int  

   set @a=  day( EOMONTH( DateADD(d, -1, @dt)))
Return @a
End
```

**Query**

```
select [dbo].[Date]('01/05/2019')
```

**Output**

```
-----------
31
```